# VB.NET Log-in via website without database how

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, authentication

I am trying to program a log-in form. I bought a domain from Wix.com and would like to run the log-in system on it. I would like registered users to be able to log in in the form and where it might even be checked whether they have a premium status or not.

I don't have access to my own members database on their site.
That's why I tried HttpWebRequest but this is also not working (Or I did something wrong).
Code:on another website as an example (HttpRequestMethode).

```
Dim User = TextBox1.Text, Pwd = TextBox2.Text
        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Login/"), HttpWebRequest)
        Request.Method = "POST"
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Dim Post As String = "email" & User & "password" & Pwd & "&useCookies=1&url="
        Dim byteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Post)
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim DataStream As Stream = Request.GetRequestStream()
        DataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        DataStream.Close()

        Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
        DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(DataStream)
        Dim ServerResponse As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        DataStream.Close()
        Response.Close()



        If InStr(ServerResponse, keyWord) Then 
            MessageBox.Show("Login nicht OK")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Login OK")
        End If
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can do it?

maybe someone among you has a better idea and maybe even a simpler one.

Comment: Are you sure your forum database supports POST requests at the URL you've set? Does this code have any error when you run it?

Comment: I think I always had this notification in the live recording: POST: HTTP/2.0 200 OK.
or is there a possibility to test whether the website offers it?

Comment: Are you able to read the response from the server (at least that's how it appears that you've been determining the login status)?

Comment: Yes I can. After the wrong login comes "POST: HTTP/2.0 200 OK". And after the correct login comes "POST: HTTP/2.0 302 Found". 
but if I put one of the two in a string. Comes every time Login OK or Login false  although I enter wrong data.

Comment: I would recommend a better way of checking if the login were accurate. If you would really like to examine the request this way, established that your server response works properly, take a look at the possible solution to do this as an alternative to InStr

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Web Request method works, you can use the `.contains` method to determine your response contains `keyWord`.

If `ServerResponse` is set to `POST: HTTP/2.0 200 OK` on failed login and it will be set to `POST: HTTP/2.0 200 FOUND` on valid login, search for the keyword or "FOUND" itself.

```
 If ServerResponse.Contains("FOUND") Then 
      'The POST text contains FOUND keyword
      MessageBox.Show("Login OK")
 Else
      'The POST text does not contain FOUND keyword
      MessageBox.Show("Login not OK")
 End If
```

Comment: tried that too. That does not work either.. Everytime Login not OK

Comment: Check your keyword and server response. I checked the sample server response, and it works properly.